# Updating detached entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Loading parents from DB, then closing context. After certain point when those parents are processed(added toys to their children, toys can be shared amongst children: many to many relationship), they need to be updated and each one is updated only once.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Toy> Toys { get; set; }
}

public class Toy
{
    public int ToyId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Child> Child { get; set; }
}
```

they have other properties, but only toys of each children are inserted. then parents are updated in DB.

```
public void UpdateParents(List<Parent> parents)
{
    using (var ctx = new Context())
    {
        foreach (var parent in parents)
        {
            parent.Children.ForEach(c => c.Toys.ForEach(
                t => ctx.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Added));

            ctx.Parents.Attach(parent);
            ctx.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Updating method works, but probably slower than this process should be. However when I tried to execute the method more times it behaved differently than first run. Each following run does not insert any new toys, instead it duplicates all Children of parents.

Is there a better and correct(update more times possible) way to do what I need?

EDIT: changing state of children to modified as well fixed my duplicates problem

```
ctx.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: It can get complex. See [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/update-entity-graph-using-dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: @SteveGreene thanks, I have added `ctx.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified;` and now it does not create duplicates and works like expected.

Do you think it can be optimized from this method?

Comment: This is what [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) is --or was-- for. You could give it a try. One thing, if *only toys of each children are inserted* there's no need to mark parents and children as `Modified`, it should be enough to attach them to the context.